# CTCI Rotate a Matrix(2D arrray) in python

Tags: python, arrays, matrix

I have been studying cracking the coding interview and one of the coding challenges is to rotate a matrix

```
Input = [
[ 5, 1, 9,11],
[ 2, 4, 8,10],
[13, 3, 6, 7],
[15,14,12,16]]

Output = [
[15,13, 2, 5],
[14, 3, 4, 1],
[12, 6, 8, 9],
[16, 7,10,11]]
```

I understand the first part of the solution

```
def rotateMatrix(matrix):
    # Transpose the Matrix
    for i in range(len(matrix)):
        for j in range(i + 1, len(matrix)):
            # Switch the row and column indices
            matrix[i][j], matrix[j][i] = matrix[j][i], matrix[i][j]
```

What I do not understand is the last part of the solution:  It looks like the nested for loop is performing some sort of swap like the above nested loop is doing, but where I get confused is "range(len(matrix[r]//2)" and then " oppI = len(matrix[r]) - 1 - i.  Is there anyone who can help shed some light on how these lines of code specifically work?  I mostly work in pandas and really need to understand more "organic" python so any help would be appreciated on this!

```
    # Reverse every row
    for r in range(len(matrix)): 
        for i in range(len(matrix[r]) // 2):
            # oppI is the opposing index to i
            oppI = len(matrix[r]) - 1 - i
            print(oppI)
            matrix[r][i], matrix[r][oppI] = matrix[r][oppI], matrix[r][i]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in second part you are just reversing the rows of the matrix.

it uses `range(len(matrix[r]//2)` to reverse first half of the list row to second half.

it's same as (after the transpose)

`new_matrix = [i[::-1] for i in matrix]`

here the matrix is transposed matrix